# xpages, notes 8.5.3 client's embedded browser, http basic authentication

Tags: http, authentication, xpages

On xpage I have code to open external web page: `window.open(pathToSiteWithHTTPBasicAuthentication)`

When user clicks on this link in notes embedded browser:
-in notes 9 this works as expected, popup widnow shows and user can enter credentials
-in notes 8.5.3 popup doesn't show and page with authentication error is opened right away

I cannot seem to find option to enable authentication popups in notes 8.5.3. embedded browser.
How can I configure this to work?

Answer (score 1):

That seems one of the things that have been fixed in Notes9. What you can/should do is to create an account document in names.nsf, then authentication is automatic. You could do that manually first to checkout how it fits and later on check for the document in your code and automatic create when missing. 
Also make sure you deal with https only when using basic authentication or someone will firesheep your credentials

Comment: Unfortunately account document doesn't work in 8.5.3 
I've checked with wireshark that user credentials have not been sent to server. So problem is basically unsolved...
In notes 9 account document works but with a twist... Popup window still displays (with no data in it) but if one clicks OK, credentials from account document are sent to server and destination page opens